# I want to add the previous number to the current number in an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

the var result should be  [4,8,15,21,11].
but i get [4,4,4,4,4].
I just can't figure out this one

```js
var numbers = [1, 3, 5, 10, 11];
var result = numbers.map(function(i) {
  var num;
  var num2;
  for (i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
    num = numbers[i];
    num2 = numbers[i + 1];
    return num + num2;
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why are you reusing the variable name `i`?

Comment: This looks a bit like homework. Put a console log in the middle of the loop.

Comment: Also, to be pedantic, the title of your question doesn't match your expected output.

Comment: The numbers array is never changed.  The for loop is not returning `num + num2` to the array or any other variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reduced way to implement this will be next one:

```js
var numbers = [1,3,5,10,11];

var result = numbers.map(
    (x, idx, arr) => idx < arr.length - 1 ? x + arr[idx + 1] : x
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Note, that the callback associated with [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) takes the following arguments:

```
var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]])
{
    // Return element for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```

Where:

- **currentValue:** The current element being processed in the array.
- **indexOptional** The index of the current element being processed in the array.
- **arrayOptional** The array map was called upon.

You can even use a traditional for loop if you are not familiarize with `map()`:

```js
var numbers = [1,3,5,10,11];
var result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i + 1])
        result.push(numbers[i] + numbers[i + 1]);
    else
        result.push(numbers[i]);
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use another loop inside the `map` method. Furthermore, you are overring the `i` value defined as `map` current value.

```js
document.body.innerText = [1, 3, 5, 10, 11].map((x, i, arr) => x + (arr[i + 1] || 0))
// --> For each iteration, returns its value + (next iteration's value, or 0 if it's the last one).
```

Answer (score 1):

The map function gives you value, and i. Your using it slightly wrong and you also don't need the for loop. Also in your forloop you were overriding the i variable form the map function.

```js
var numbers = [1,3,5,10,11];
var result = numbers.map(function(num, i, arr){
  if (arr[i + 1]) {
    return num + arr[i + 1];
  }
  return num;
});
console.log('result', result);
console.log('expected',  [4, 8, 15, 21, 11]);
```